# how to relate roles in filter attribute with my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

What's the data source Asp.net MVC uses to see if the user is in which role. And how can i change it so that it works with my own database table (when i write `[Autorize(Roles="admin")]` it checks in the table if the user is in the role )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the data source Asp.net MVC uses to see if the user is in which role.

It uses the `RoleProvider` that is configured in your web.config. If you want to use custom tables you could write a [`custom role provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by inheriting from the [`RoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) class and implementing the abstract members. The [`IsUserInRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.isuserinrole%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method is the one that you should always implement because that's what will be used in this case:

```
public class MyRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        // go and hit your custom datasource to verify if the user 
        // is in the required role and return true or false from this
        // method
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could register your custom role provider in web.config in order to replace the default one:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider"> 
        <providers> 
            <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="Mynamespace.MyRoleProvider" /> 
        </providers> 
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

And if you don't want to be using any providers (judging from your [`previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913271/why-using-telling-net-about-provider) that seems to be the case) then you should write a custom `Authorize` attribute which is not using a role provider at all but is using some custom code of yours:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // no user is authenticated => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        // at this stage we have an authenticated user
        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return IsInRole(username, this.Roles);
    }

    private bool static IsInRole(string username, string roles)
    {
        // the username parameter will contain the currently authenticated user
        // the roles parameter will contain the string specified in the attribute
        // (for example "admin")
        // so here go and hit your custom tables and verify if the user is
        // in the required role
        ... 
    }
}
```

and finally decorate your controller action with this custom attribute instead of relying on the default one which is based on the role provider:

```
[MyAutorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: great post, thank you very much, that helps so much, i have 2 weeks looking  for this, i have downloaded 3 ebooks about asp.net mvc 4 and i haven't found this, can u tell me when have you learned this (kind of ebook title)

Comment: Well, you spent 2 weeks while I have spent 10 years working on line of business applications on the ASP.NET platform. That's how I learned it.

Comment: the function is gerolesforuser() and not IsUserInRole, I think you need more than 10 years :)

Comment: Thank you @DarinDimitrov. This is what I have been looking for since past 2 weeks. Finally solved my issue. However, I want to authorize multiple roles on the action method like below.                [MyAutorize(Roles = "admin | member")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}                                                                                            How should I use the authorize attribute?

Comment: @ajexpress, you could always split the string with some separator and then authorize for each of the roles.